# Vertex of a polyhedron which is related to Sudoku

Tags: combinatorics, polyhedra

Let $x_{ij}$ where $i,j\in [n]$ be variables. Consider the polyhedron defined by:

$x_{ii}=0$, $x_{ij}\geq 0$. For each $i$,  $\sum_{j=1}^nx_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^nx_{ji}=y_i$ for some fixed constant $y_i>0$.

Provided that the polyhedron is non-empty, what are the vertices of this polyhedron?

Another way to describe the polyhedron is that we have a set of $n\times n$ square matrix $X$, where the diagonals of $X$ are zero, each entry of $X$ is non-negative, and the sum of $i$-th row and $i$-th column both equal to a constant $y_i>0$.

For $y_1=y_2=\cdots=y_n=y$, the vertices are the set where $x_{ij}=y$ for $(i,j)\in S$ and $x_{ij}=0$ for $(i,j)\notin S$. Here $S$ is an index set such that:

(a) $S$ contains $n$ elements;

(b) for any $(i,j), (i',j')\in S$, if $(i,j)\neq(i',j')$ then $i\neq i'$ and $j\neq j'$; (In some sense (a) and (b) describes the set of possible positions for each number in a Sudoku)

(c) $(i,i)\notin S$ for any $i\in [n]$.

However, I am stuck on the general case. Any thoughts?

Edit: BTW I would also be interested to know when this polyhedron is empty.

Comment: In the 2x2 case it's trivial; have you considered working explicitly on the 3x3 case just to get a sense for the shape of it?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I have thought about that. Note that in the $2\times 2$ case we have 2 variables and 4 equalities, in the $3\times 3$ case we have 6 variables and 6 equalities (5 of them are linearly independent though), and as $n$ goes larger we certainly would have more wiggle room.

Comment: Just wanted to point out what you probably already know: $S$ is simply a permutation without any fixed points.

Comment: These are particular _transportation polytopes_. Lots is known about them. What you want to know may be in the literature somewhere. A search finds lots of entry points.